# Vue, how to handle errors when using axios calls

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to work out on how to handle errors when using axios. Please see the code below:

```
//Admin.vue

methods: {
    saveClicked: function(){

      updateConfig(this.editedConfig)
        .then(response => {
          console.log("in here");
          console.log(response);
          this.info.showAlert = true;
          this.info.message = "Successfully updated config!!"
          this.info.alertType = "success";
          this.showJsonEditor = !this.showJsonEditor;

        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.info.showAlert = true;
          this.info.message = "Failed to update config, please try again later"
          this.info.alertType = "error";
        });
    }
}

//network.js

function updateConfig(editedConfig){

  return axios.put(URL,editedConfig, {
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json"
    }
  })
      .then(response => response)
      .catch(error => error);
}
```

When the requests is successful, everything is fine. I get my alert saying all is good.

I forced my backend to return an error for every request so i can simulate error behaviour in my Vue application and this is what i observed:

Even when error is received. The the program is going through `then()` in `Admin.vue`check the image below:

[image]

What have i missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question: Why did you added:

```
   .then(response => response)
   .catch(error => error);
```

in your `network.js` file?

I guess You have some misunderstanding of Promise.

From the API [`Promise.prototype.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) will return an other promise. This **new** Promise will serve either as a way to compose something to do on success or catch exception.

From the API [`Promise.prototype.catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) will return an other promise. This **new** Promise is a bit different. From the doc:

> The Promise returned by catch() is rejected if onRejected throws an error or returns a Promise which is itself rejected; otherwise, it is resolved.

So in your case it will call the `resolve` from the next `then` call. Unless you throw error in the `network.js` file which is pointless.

Remove the 2 line in the `network.js` file and you will have your intended behaviour.